# Facebook Conversion "Same Event ID" error

Tags: facebook

Getting this message:

> Same event ID received for many event instances
> You're sending the same event ID for many instances of your ViewContent events. Event IDs are unique identifiers that are used to deduplicate identical events received from your pixel and the Conversions API so they're not counted twice. To ensure that Facebook is accurately counting your events, each unique event instance needs its own unique event ID.
> This may cause issues with the measurement of your events and the attribution of your ad campaigns.

So we've added IDs, and it's got to the point we've made a ridiculous function to make generate IDs:

```
function timePlusUuid4() {
    return (Date.now().toString()) + '-' + ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
            (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
    );
}
```

Every conversion event is using it:

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', data, { eventID: timePlusUuid4() });
```

But we cannot get the error to go away. There is no other place conversions happen on the website.

Of course FB pixel helper, and FB test event function, show it working flawlessly.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

don't use time

i had the same problem using time...

or try to add '' around the value